# Variable from PHP into jQuery to form a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, anchor

I have a table with the following PHP code:

```
<table id="myTable">
        <tr class="header">
            <th>Naam</th>
            <th>Bedrijf</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        include 'assets/scripts/connect.php';
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `admin`='0' AND `deleted`='0'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
            ?>
            <tr class="trash" onclick="deletePopUp()" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
             <td><?php echo $row['fname']; ?> <?php echo $row['lname']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row['company']; ?></td>
            </tr>

           <?php
                }
            ?>
</table>
```

As you can see, I add a data-id for each row that is created by the code in conjunction with the database. The onClick function makes a modal pop up with the request to confirm whether the user really wants to delete this customer. The modal is coded the following way:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-top">
        <h1>Weet je het zeker?</h1>
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-inner">
        <a href="delete-user.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" id="delete" class="btn-confirm">Verwijderen</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-cancel cancel">Annuleren</a>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

The two anchor tags are for the confirmation. So one sould go to the external PHP script to delete the customer according to their ID. I use the GET method for this. But the link on the modal now forms always with the same ID. Do the link is always:

/assets/scripts/delete-user.php?id=2

I would like to have the ID being the same as that of the customer clicked on.

I tried using jQuery to form this link, but I get the same result. This is the jQuery I used:

```
var id=$('.trash').data('id');
$('#delete').attr('href','/assets/scripts/delete-user.php?id='+id);
```

But as said, this gives the same result.

How can I get the link on the modal to have a dynamic ID?

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will adapt it. It doesn't awnser my question as for now though

Comment: Take care.... using a link to delete information is a bad idea, any bots following links will trigger the delete.

Comment: @Vbudo I understand that, but I am not that concerned about that as this is a admin enviroment, which is protected. Also, I do not actually delete the user, but just change the Boolean in the database connected to the cell deleted. If you know of any better solution, I would gladly hear it from you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you added an inline js event handler function I would suggest to use the parameters:

- event:  the event object
- this:   the current element

In your case your may write:

`<tr class="trash" onclick="deletePopUp(event, this)" data-id="This is An ID">`

Therefore, your deletePopUp function will be:

```
function deletePopUp(e, ele) {
    var id = ele.dataset['id'];  // get current data-id
    $('#delete').attr('href','/assets/scripts/delete-user.php?id='+id);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

The snippet:

```js
function deletePopUp(e, ele) {
  var id = ele.dataset['id'];
  $('#delete').attr('href','/assets/scripts/delete-user.php?id='+id);
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}


$('#delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.href);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>Bedrijf</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trash" onclick="deletePopUp(event, this)" data-id="This is An ID">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>company</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-top">
            <h1>Weet je het zeker?</h1>
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-inner">
            <a href="delete-user.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" id="delete" class="btn-confirm">Verwijderen</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn-cancel cancel">Annuleren</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Gidimotje Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

A simpler method to above could be:
(I haven't tested this, I assume this does what you need)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".trash").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $("#delete").attr("href","delete-user.php?id="+id);
    });
});
```